# MongoDB Kafka Connector not generating the message key with the Mongo document id

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm using the beta release of the [MongoDB Kafka Connector to publish from MongoDB to a Kafka topic.](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/docs/source.md)

Messages are generated into Kafka but their key is null when it should be the document id:

[image]

This is my **connect standalone config**:

```
bootstrap.servers=xxx:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter you want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable and must be specified, but most users will
# always want to use the built-in default. Offset and config data is never visible outside of Kafka Connect in this format.
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

And the **mongodb source properties**:

```
name=mongo-source
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

# Connection and source configuration
connection.uri=mongodb+srv://xxx
database=mydb
collection=mycollection

topic.prefix=someprefix
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=5000

# Change stream options
pipeline=[]
batch.size=0
change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
collation=
```

Below there's an example of a message String value:

```
"{\"_id\": {\"_data\": \"xxx\"}, \"operationType\": \"replace\", \"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1564140389, \"i\": 1}}, \"fullDocument\": {\"_id\": \"5\", \"name\": \"Some Client\", \"clientId\": \"someclient\", \"clientSecret\": \"1234\", \"whiteListedIps\": [], \"enabled\": true, \"_class\": \"myproject.Client\"}, \"ns\": {\"db\": \"mydb\", \"coll\": \"mycollection\"}, \"documentKey\": {\"_id\": \"5\"}}"
```

I tried using a transform to extract if from the value, specifically from the documentKey field:

```
transforms=InsertKey
transforms.InsertKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.InsertKey.fields=documentKey
```

But got an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Struct objects supported for [copying fields from value to key], found: java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireStruct(Requirements.java:52)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.applyWithSchema(ValueToKey.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.apply(ValueToKey.java:65)
```

Any ideas to generate a key with the document id?

Comment: How about `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` ?

Comment: I just tried and same result key -> null

Comment: I see. Essentially, you'd have to extract `documentKey` and and then you also need to extract the inner `_id` field.

Comment: That’s it... I keep trying with ValueToKey transform but no luck yet

Answer (score 2):

According to exception, that is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Struct objects supported for [copying fields from value to key], found: java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireStruct(Requirements.java:52)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.applyWithSchema(ValueToKey.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.apply(ValueToKey.java:65)
```

Unfortunately [Mongo DB connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/docs/source.md), that you use, it doesn't create *properly schema*.

Above connector create Record with key and value schema's as `String`.
Check this line:: [How record is created by connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mongodb/kafka/connect/source/MongoSourceTask.java#L137). That is the reason why you can't apply Transformation to it

Comment: update `this line`
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/r0.2/src/main/java/com/mongodb/kafka/connect/source/MongoSourceTask.java#L137

Answer (score 0):

This should be supported in release 1.3.0:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/KAFKA-40

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll keep an eye on it.